# Insights into Azure Table Storage egress data

Tags: azure, logging, storage

We are observing huge egress from our azure table queries. We have enabled Diagnostic settings and are able to query logs in Log Analytics Workspace. We do however like to look at the data itself that is getting transferred. Is it possible to do so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure log analytics by default log any data itself. Probably you have to explicitly log it in order to see it. However, the cost of logging gets out of hand very easily, if not controlled properly.  I would say that your app sends processed data in the form of a DEBUG log rather than an INFO log. Then send all of your DEBUG log either to some file in a storage account or send it to a Log Analytics workspace. This way, you will be able to switch between INFO and DEBUG as a part of the external configuration of your app. Never use the DEBUG in the production unless you are masking your Processed data.